# SVG is offset in navbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am making my webpage in ReactTS. I made a navbar and I wanted to add some SVGs from MUI Material Icons. But my only problem is that the SVG is a bit too high:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJFaw.png)

Already tried setting the position to `inherit` but also had no effect, here is the CSS:

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  background-color: #3e424d;
  color: white;
}

svg {
  position: inherit;
}
```

Could anyone help me? I am not good at CSS

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the svgs height.  Try adding display:flex, align-items: center to the svg

Comment: @Marshall ~~Worked but now the SVG is inside the text but the height is fixed now!~~ Fixed it by removing the `position: inherit;` tag! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Marshall, I could fix it by adding:

```css
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

(Also removed `position: inherit;`)